# Accessing sub-objects of an object without using any

Tags: typescript

I'm in the process of applying better TypeScript to a project. There is a complex object coming from my backend which is a class with dozens of attributes, most of which are classes of their own. We have a form with a common change handler that currently has a few `any`s in it to make it work, but I'd like to fix that with generics.

This is a simplified version of the pattern in my application, but I am able to reproduce the same errors I'm seeing:

```
class PhoneNumber {
  prefix: number;
  exchange: number;
  line: number;
}

class Address {
  address1: string;
  address2: string;
  city: string;
}

class User {
  phone: PhoneNumber;
  address: Address;
}

const user = new User();

function setValue<A extends keyof User, T extends User[A], K extends keyof T, V extends T[K]>(
  value: V,
  fieldType: new () => T,
  fieldName: A,
  fieldAttribute: K
) {

  if (!user[fieldName]) {
    user[fieldName] = new fieldType();
  }

  const field = user[fieldName];

  // error here.
  field[fieldAttribute] = value;
}

setValue(408, PhoneNumber, 'phone', 'prefix');
```

I tried a few things, and this is as close as I'm able to get to a solution. I'm able to inspect the function call at the end in my IDE, and it looks like the generics are being filled with something sane: `function setValue<"phone", PhoneNumber, "prefix", number>()`, but then I get an error during compilation:

> TS2536: Type 'K' cannot be used to index type 'User[A]'.

Am I going about this the wrong way?  If I can't figure this out, I'm going to end up just splitting out the different types into separate handlers.

There's also a case where some of the fields are arrays of objects, which adds another wrinkle to the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the current argument types of `setValue`, one could provide a *child* class B as `fieldType` (which *extends* `user[fieldName]` class A), and target a `fieldAttribute` of B, which may not exist in A:

```
class PhoneNumber2 extends PhoneNumber {
  extension: number;
}

// Complies with setValue types,
// but if `user` already has a basic PhoneNumber instance,
// the code within setValue fails
setValue(408, PhoneNumber2, "phone", "extension");

// within setValue:
user["phone"]["extension"] = 408;
// ...but user["phone"] may be a PhoneNumber,
// not necessarily a PhoneNumber2!
```

In your case, instead of `K extends keyof T` (T being the return type of fieldType, potentially a child class), you could just use `K extends keyof User[A]`, to make sure the fieldAttribute targets the base class:

```
function setValue2<A extends keyof User, T extends User[A], K extends keyof User[A], V extends T[K]>(
  value: V,
  fieldType: new () => T,
  fieldName: A,
  fieldAttribute: K
) {

  if (!user[fieldName]) {
    user[fieldName] = new fieldType();
  }

  const field = user[fieldName];

  field[fieldAttribute] = value; // Now okay
}

setValue2(408, PhoneNumber, 'phone', 'prefix');
setValue2(408, PhoneNumber2, 'phone', 'prefix');
setValue2(408, PhoneNumber2, 'phone', 'extension'); // Error: Argument of type '"extension"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof PhoneNumber'.
```

You could even get rid of the generic type `T`:

```
function setValue3<A extends keyof User, K extends keyof User[A], V extends User[A][K]>(
    value: V,
    fieldType: new () => User[A],
    fieldName: A,
    fieldAttribute: K
) {}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKAWB7AdgUwHIFcC2AjVATtAN4BQ0F0ADgagGYCWAHgFzTI75EC80ADAG5oAemHQAIjmwBPaA2QMALgzAhoAN1WZU0AFaYIi6IsTQw6xAwAm0ACoBlaIQKIi84-AYwIDbFRAMjKg2qExgfiCo5JShwPBgyADmqGwceITQvILRFAFoqZwZWQKkAL6kpKCQMACCVla0UCQ5ZvWNEACMbIYE8omZ0ABEgyWUrQ2oUABM3Yq9SQPDo5TAStKz8-28S2UVVU0AqhAZZGNUSPlwFxiFPOyoAO5XKDfpBAAUAJTLFGBtkxA2HUJk1eGgnsD2l8SuVKihDNADEV7k8joRoRU6JhkMBlChoMdFAA1LSoAA8NScTEUqGQVhgAGtUNJEHRoGiCAAaOxUml0mAcgDaNQAutyANK82n06BMlls2zcolS-l2QXikUAPneLU0IG0bCJnJaQRAVls0ioKRR0C+mU1dmNY1NVnQ4WtNSdlBdNUUcwYuEwNLY4tIn2aLUCtoAhEiCIKXW7sKgReHTmNKHGEwxUGakymBuDoC6LVaMWNYWNgPCjC6BlnE+6RSUWqInAQXER4IRUAA6E05s3Z3NWX3+wM0kUDPXaIRtgCiHdcbFLOgA5OK19BgAlkIgjPhEccbCY5HTQsZLeuhaK1-3YYSSfrUO8ACx8AAc3IQLywb25a7nC8a4ATQ9DMGu3x7OATQ-mgf5cFMKoynBrxcM0YyhHyPgoAUbwDHwuykG2ADqSjwNumAdrSRiPqSZgEIkOA0ZeVoQMabYvHIMCqCAiAPMEximIoYCMagRhgMWg6jn6vQTjorLEWIkkAMIABIAJIADLiNuMEwKy7LHPGjbJmKSnQA83a0JAchGNWmBmtuKAie4KAgLICRnoYCTAApbKKN20C4JADDANQoksfsECkHRz5vp+37XAhhBTNygxAWggzpVhtI4cggxQaQWI4niyAEuJT7aFMFLIYyzKGRy3K2HVRmEMKYrQJKuWqnKjXGR1SqtbY6pajqYwztaRoDiOq6pI8trhtwDqKjNebukCXoUD6skBkG1qhmmFRjFG7yxgNpkpkdGaZhd0n5lOYILSWV7lpQlYrDWUkjvWd0jg9LbOtJw5mmOcn7Y9GiknOYjoPx0CIAyYDSERcXVQlX7PPBtygdcIHQIBtCMEwkElGjqBTBjSW-rcaUE5lqD44T4Ek1B5OU++mOoSlBB04BeMAT1+WkyIYiLp2QKMcxyBGIZihXgTgxCwwKCDFuXjsPuZhQAwiTIGAuCREJEUEO6NJEHLCtrn1bLc7cd6YtiuIq+V5MAMy1T1Mo221XJda1Ps3p1ypewKA2iqN2q6qShpbd9ZpzTadrLb7g1ra6G3QJ66dg3twZdWGEYnWyZ0NvdTbXTdR7tZdkNFi9ZZQRWx2fcgCJ1rwZf-U2gPesDO3jhD07Q6L0D2MoIBqIjyOo5VpJu1TWNoYQuPAaBRMQWzc-PgvnPU9jbx8wzTNgcTIttgA8kjKPu4vduH6vaBM8rKDn2LS4EJLTHJjLCMBVbStqR5RdmrbimsJI6z1gbI2p4qCiTNhkS2VoCY+3vlwB2QA)

Comment: Thanks, this got me past the problem.  In my actual use case, I forgot that all of the properties of the class were marked as optional (even though they are not in practice) but I was able to solve that with a mapped type

`export type NonOptionalUser = {
  [Property in keyof User]-?: User[Property];
}`